# What is my syntax error in my Provider component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help!
https://gyazo.com/c5982a3511467c8ca895ef8ddf708ef1[Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; (20:17)](https://gyazo.com/c5982a3511467c8ca895ef8ddf708ef1)

My component has a syntax error, no idea why I get
 ./src/Provider/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; (20:17)

18 |     }
  19 |

> 20 |        render()  {
>        |                  ^
>     21 |
>     22 |           return (
>     23 |

```
class index extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        books: [],
        currentlyReading:[],
        wantToRead:[],
        read:[],
        addBooks: books => {

    }
}

   render()  {

      return (
         <MyContext.Provider 

        value={{...this.state}}>
      {this.props.children}


       </MyContext.Provider>)
}
}
```

export default index;

Comment: missing a comma before the `render()`

Answer (score 1):

```
 constructor() { // <- 1
    super();
    this.state = { // <- 2
      books: [],
      currentlyReading:[],
      wantToRead:[],
      read:[],
      addBooks: books => { // <- 3

  } // < - 3
 } // < - 2
 // <- 1 ???
```

You are missing a closing `}` to close the constructor. Therefore `render() { /*..*/ }` is a syntax error as it is inside the methods body and not in the classes body.

Comment: right and that's followed by 2 `}` oh oh wait I see. I wish people could indent properly.

Comment: Thank you guys!! Jonas + @Pointy

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put parentheses around the arrow function's return value

```
  addBooks: books => ({

  })
```

And you are also missing `}` for the constructor.

Here's what the code should look like

```
class index extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      books: [],
      currentlyReading:[],
      wantToRead:[],
      read:[],
      // you were missing parenthesis here
      addBooks: books => ({

      })
    }
  // you were also missing this } here
  }

  render()  {

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider 

      value={{...this.state}}>
        {this.props.children}


      </MyContext.Provider>)
  }
}
```

Note:
The reason you have to wrap arrow function's return value in a parenthesis is because it's an object literal. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_Syntax)

Comment: Am I missing the  } for the cosntructor? I think I have it.. Sorry, i'm a newbie                            
       constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            books: [],
            currentlyReading:[],
            wantToRead:[],
            read:[],
            addBooks: books =>() ({
            
        })
    }

Comment: I added parentheses a  addBooks: books => ({

  })

Comment: @ruxi is it fixed? I added what your code should look like

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error:  Line 3:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first                                                                                                                               import React, { Component} from 'react';
export const MyContext = React.createContext();
import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'

Comment: That means your syntax error is fixed. Do you know why you had to parenthesis to the arrow function?

Comment: @ruxi You need to put all the `import` statements at the top of the file.

Comment: It's fixed!! OMG, THANK YOU so much. I'm totally new at this. I have a project due, this is too much information for me in too short period of time.You are the best, can't thank you enough! @Rashmirathi

Comment: Great! no problem. Do you understand what the issues were?